# Приоритет операторов в условных операторах

Tags: java

Добрый день.

Задание:

> Given a string, if the string "del" appears starting at index 1, return a string where that "del" has been deleted. Otherwise, return the string unchanged.
>
> delDel("adelbc") → "abc"
>
> delDel("adelHello") → "aHello"
>
> delDel("adedbc") → "adedbc"

Выводит для строк в которых три символа и меньше:

> Exception:java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4 (line number:4).

Пробовал метод `replaceAll()` использовать такая же ошибка.

Вопрос:

Но в условии явно указал `str.length() >= 4` т.е ошибка не должна возникать.

```
public String delDel(String str) {
  

  if (str.substring(1,4).equals("del") && str.length() >= 4){
    
    return str.substring(0,1) + str.substring(4);
  }
    
    return str;   
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вычисление условия идет слева-направо. Оператор && значит, что если выражение слева не соответствует условию, то выражения справа вычисления не требует (код после оператора `if` выполнятся не будет уже при `false` в левом операторе и вычислять правый нет необходимости).

То есть, сначала вы пытаетесь получить подстроку и получаете экзепшен о выходе из диапазона, если строка меньше 5 символов, до проверки на длину строки дело вообще не доходит.

Вам нужно сначала проверять длину строки, а потом уже вырезать из нее подстроки.

Answer (score 2):

Длину строки надо проверять **до** того как вы получаете подстроку, а не после.